# TeX capacity exceeded when changing font size in foreach loop which is inside an axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach

I have a `node` in a `foreach` loop inside an `axis` environment. Now I want to change the font size of the text inside the `node`. For example in the MWE below I want to change `{\t}` into `{\footnotesize \t}`, but this results into a `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]`.

What trickery do I need here?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot {x};
    \foreach \y/ \t in {2/Text 1, -2/Text 2}{
        \edef\temp{\noexpand \node at (axis cs:0, \y) {\t};}
            \temp
        }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image: Graph]

Comment: `\noexpand\footnotesize\t`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `\noexpand` in front of `\node` in order not to expand it in the `\edef`; do the same for `\footnotesize`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot {x};
    \foreach \y/\t in {2/Text 1, -2/Text 2}{
        \edef\temp{\noexpand \node at (axis cs:0, \y) {\noexpand\footnotesize\t};}
        \temp
        }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```